# Show a collection of values in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to have a collection of values in jekyll and then format them as table?

I tried something like this in my .md file:

```
---
layout: tutorial
title: Jekyll
reqs:
 - name: names here
   desc: description here
   value: value
 - name: names here
   desc: description here
   value: value
---
```

In my tutorial layout I have this:

```
---
layout: home
---

{% for item in page.reqs %}
  {{ item.name }}
  {{ item.desc }}
  {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

The html code for the table was removed. The problem is my for loop prints nothing. The page is empty except for what was inherited from the other layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a YAML problem. You're mixing up the array and dictionary syntaxes. Try something like this instead:

```
---
layout: tutorial
title: Jekyll
reqs:
 - item1:
     name: names here
     desc: description here
     value: value
 - item2:
     name: names here
     desc: description here
     value: value
---
```

Now your for loop is looping through an array of dictionaries (`item1, item2...`) whose values you can use in your output.